# int to double conversion in http request

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter. While I was trying to hit HTTP request int values in http request are being converted to double values in Flutter. Below is the http response while i'm hitting through flutter service:

```
{
   "GS": 1.0,
   "DATA": {
      "XXXX": 13,
      "XXXX": "Managing",
      "XXXX": "F6ACEE86D6E6",
      "XXXX": "Santhosh Reddy",
      "PHONE": 9.652823823E9,
      "EMAIL": "",
      "DISPLAYMESSAGE": "Successfull."
   },
   "RS": 1.0
}
```

The actual response while checking through serviceUrl is as below:

```
{
   "GS": 1,
   "DATA": {
      "XXXX": 13,
      "XXXX": "Managing",
      "XXXX": "F6ACEE86D6E6",
      "XXXX": "Santhosh Reddy",
      "PHONE": 9652823823,
      "EMAIL": "",
      "DISPLAYMESSAGE": "Successfull."
   },
   "RS": 1
}.
```

Comment: Dart doesn't do that. it has to be your code that does that.

Comment: I was getting integer values while checking the service in postman also.

Comment: Which sounds like the server actually is sending integer, not double.

Comment: Yes that's correct . but while coming to flutter app, the integer value is being converted. I'm searching for sources that can handle this issue

Comment: Do you find any solution for above issue? @KURRUHEM